# Download a file from a website in R

Tags: r

I am trying to download the Access file in this website http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/Estacao.asp?Codigo=2043018 through R. Actually, the page directs to where I should click on a button to download the Access file. But I'll have to download hundreds of files from this page and it will change only the last code. If I do it one by one, I'm gonna spend a lot of time. I will do it with a loop, but firstly I must find out how to download the file.

Anyone could give a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html is useful.

Answer (score -1):

A loop and [`download.file`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html) should do this.

Comment: No, it won't. The initial URL has a javacript-based `<a>` tag which will require RSelenium to use. Eventually `download.file` may work, but not until he scripts page navigation.